# How to return a date using dateformatter in Swift?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I have a little problem and I don't know how can I solve it. I have a closedRange of dates which i'm using with a DatePicker.

How can I have a date with that format that I have in the code bellow ?

```
  var minMaxRange : ClosedRange<Date> {
        return dateStart...dateEnd
    }
```

I want the datePicker to start from the current date, and dateEnd is coming from the backend. dateEnd is a string so I do not have problem with this.

```
    var dateStart : Date {
        let isoDate = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        return dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate)
    }
    
    var dateEnd : Date {
        let isoDate = syncViewModel.schedule[0].end
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
        return dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate) ?? Date.now
    }
```

Comment: Date from isoDate doesn’t make any sense

Comment: You either have a `Date` or a `String` representation of a date. `DateFormatter` is the tool that converts `Date` to `String` and viceversa. You are trying to convert a date to a date. And that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `Date`... just write `var dateStart = Date()`.

Then, you can format both dates (start and end) to a string when you show them on the screen, using:

`dateFormatter.string(from: dateStart)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var minMaxRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
    .now ... dateEnd
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you are passing a valid date string to your dateEnd computed property. Note that returning a new date object in case of failure doesn't make any sense unless you want your range to be empty if it fails.